# Mac mini Server Late 2009 cannot connect to network on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, broadcom, mac

I cannot connect my computer to the network.  The Wi-Fi does not appear to be recognized at all within Ubuntu.  The ethernet jack shows up, and I can see the wired connection in Settings, but the switch to toggle it on is greyed out.  I tried using an Android phone to establish a USB network connection, and it also appears in Settings, but the toggle switch is also greyed out.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) Also instructions for OFFLINE installation (not easy). Getting a temporary internet connection is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with a Macbook Pro 2009, which has a very similar hardware setup. The issue was that the Broadcom Wifi Driver was not installed.

Assuming you can get Internet Access to the Mac Mini either via Ethernet or tethering with your cellphone, then you can run the following commands in Terminal and WiFi should work. Rebooting was not required based on my experience.

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Hopefully this helps and good luck.

Comment: I cannot connect to the internet by ethernet or phone tethering.